# How to work with Blob when trying to insert image into Sqlite database?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-layout

I am new in Android dev.
I am trying to create Android app with SQlite. I have a problem with inserting image in Blob. Text is easy to insert, but problem is with image. I know I need to use Blob, but question is, **where to use it ? I need to use Imageview in my layout ?** 
I need to clic to image button, then insert image from SD card or mobile and then it save into Sqlite database with text. After it, retrive from Sqlite database.

Thank you for your attention and help.

**There is my code:**
MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText etName,etRoll,etAddress,etBranch,etEmail,etImage;
Button btnSubmit,btngetdata,btndroptable;
DatabaseHelpher helpher;
List<DatabaseModel> dbList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    dbList= new ArrayList<DatabaseModel>();
    etName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etRoll = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etRoll);
    etAddress =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
    etBranch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etBranch);
    etEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etImage = (Image)findViewById(R.id.image);      // ????
    btnSubmit  =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    btngetdata =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btngetdata);

    btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));

           // startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class));

        }
    });

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String name=etName.getText().toString();
            String email=etEmail.getText().toString();
            String roll=etRoll.getText().toString();
            String address=etAddress.getText().toString();
            String branch=etBranch.getText().toString();
            Blob image=etImage

        if(name.equals("") || email.equals("") || roll.equals("") ||address.equals("")||branch.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please fill all the fields",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {
            helpher = new DatabaseHelpher(MainActivity.this);
            helpher.insertIntoDB(name, email, roll, address, branch, image);
        }
            etName.setText("");
            etRoll.setText("");
            etAddress.setText("");
            etBranch.setText("");
            etEmail.setText("");


            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "insert value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        }
    });

}}
```

**DatabaseModel.java:**

```
 public class DatabaseModel {
    private String name;
    private String roll;
    private String address;
    private String branch;
    private String email;
    private String image;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRoll() {
        return roll;
    }

    public void setRoll(String roll) {
        this.roll = roll;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getBranch() {
        return branch;
    }

    public void setBranch(String branch) {
        this.branch = branch;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage (byte[] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

**DatabaseHelper.java:**

```
 public class DatabaseHelpher extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="student";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String STUDENT_TABLE = "stureg";
    private static final String STU_TABLE = "create table "+STUDENT_TABLE +"(name TEXT,email TEXT primary key,roll TEXT,address TEXT,branch TEXT,,image BLOB)";

    Context context;

    public DatabaseHelpher(final Context context) {
        super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(STU_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + STUDENT_TABLE);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insertIntoDB(String name,String email,String roll,String address,String branch,byte[]image_data){
        Log.d("insert", "before insert");

        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("name", name);
        values.put("email", email);
        values.put("roll", roll);
        values.put("address", address);
        values.put("branch", branch);
        values.put("image", image_data);

        // 3. insert
        db.insert(STUDENT_TABLE, null, values);
        // 4. close
        db.close();
        Toast.makeText(context, "insert value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        Log.i("insert into DB", "After insert");



    }


    public List<DatabaseModel> getDataFromDB(){
        List<DatabaseModel> modelList = new ArrayList<DatabaseModel>();
        String query = "select * from "+STUDENT_TABLE;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                DatabaseModel model = new DatabaseModel();
                model.setName(cursor.getString(0));
                model.setEmail(cursor.getString(1));
                model.setRoll(cursor.getString(2));
                model.setAddress(cursor.getString(3));
                model.setBranch(cursor.getString(4));
                model.setImage(cursor.getBlob(5));  //Add byte paramter in your DatabaseModel
                modelList.add(model);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }


        Log.d("student data", modelList.toString());


        return modelList;
    }



    public void deleteARow(String email){
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(STUDENT_TABLE, "email" + " = ?", new String[] { email });
        db.close();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.layout:**

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Enter Email"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etEmail"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Enter Branch"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etBranch"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Enter Address"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etAddress"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Enter Roll"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etRoll"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Enter Name"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etName"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="uložit do databáze"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btngetdata"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Zobrazit seznam rumů"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity_details.layout**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="name"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:textSize="36sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/roll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Roll"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Address"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/branch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Branch"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Email"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/image"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Where to add the image view ? When I trying into layout, I don't know, where to impelement code into java classes ??
I need to help, now where to find how to do it. I need to hlep in my code, because it my homework. Please someone please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Save images in database is not good practice (save in folder is more beautiful).

But... **How converter image view in byte[]**

```
image                        = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.qrcode);
Bitmap bitmap                = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
byte[] image=stream.toByteArray();
```

Then save you image byte[] in dataBase.

Comment: Thank for com. But where to write this code, into class DatabaseHelper or MainActivity ? And what to write into layout ?

Comment: in your onClickListener create a variable byte[] with algorithm above, and call your **helpher.insertIntoDB(name, email, roll, address, branch, imageByteArray);** You are already doing 90% of that, just need to pass the byte [] to the method

Answer (score 0):

For @Peterr

What is wrong here ?

```
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        String name=etName.getText().toString();
        String email=etEmail.getText().toString();
        String roll=etRoll.getText().toString();
        String address=etAddress.getText().toString();
        String branch=etBranch.getText().toString();
        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);   //error on image????
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap(); //error on image ????
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
        byte[] image=stream.toByteArray();


    if(name.equals("") || email.equals("") || roll.equals("") ||address.equals("")||branch.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please fill all the fields",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else {
        helpher = new DatabaseHelpher(MainActivity.this);
        helpher.insertIntoDB(name, email, roll, address, branch, imageByteArray); //red is ImageByteArray ????
    }
        etName.setText("");
        etRoll.setText("");
        etAddress.setText("");
        etBranch.setText("");
        etEmail.setText("");


        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "insert value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
```

**Is referent you ImageView component in XML layout**.

In your second line of activity, you are declaring image EditText, this not is EditText, this is ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Steps :

1. obtain the image from image view.
2. convert image to byte array.
3. pass the byte array as data/parameter in your query for database